# Acceder a tabla agregada a base de datos de wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Hola estoy desarrollando un plugin para actualizar el stock de mi tienda fisica cada vez que haya una venta en wordpress. Para ello tengo que acceder a una tabla (productos) que he añadido a la base de datos de wordpress. Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Plugin Name: miPlugin
 * Plugin URI: 
 * Description: Actualiza el stock de la tienda fisica
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: 
 * Author URI: 
 * License: GPL2
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'rudr_complete' );

function rudr_complete( $order_id ) {
    
        
    $database="database";
    $user="user";
    $password="password";
    $mydb = new wpdb($user,$password,$database,'localhost');

    //$db = new mysqli("localhost", $user, $password, $database);
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        
        
    mail("luilli.guillan@gmail.com", "fuera del bucle","viva el vino");
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

        $product        = $item->get_product();    
        $item_quantity  = $item->get_quantity(); // Get the item quantity               
        $item_sku = $product->get_sku();
            
        $cantidad = $item_quantity;
        $referencia = $item_sku;

        $result = $mydb->get_results('SELECT unidades FROM productos WHERE codigo_de_barras = "'.$referencia.'"');
            
        mail("luilli.guillan@gmail.com", "dentro del bucle",$result);           
    }    
}?>
```

de manera que en $result deberia de obtener el numero de unidades del producto que hay en la tienda fisica, pero $result parece estar vacia, ya que en el email que mando no muestra nada en el body.

Comment: revisa el resultado de  `get_results(` antes de enviar el mail puede que este devolviendo null

Answer (score 0):

en WordPress, simplemente haciendo uso del objeto global $wpdb, ya tienes acceso a la base de datos directamente. Comprueba que en el string donde haces la consulta, todos los campos y el nombre de la base de datos, estén encerrados entre acentos abiertos (`) para que no tengas problemas en la consulta. También tienes que asegurarte que el nombre de la base de datos sea el correcto, porque según como la hayas creado, es posible que WordPress le haya añadido un sufijo, por ejemplo "wp_productos".
El código quedaría algo así:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Plugin Name: miPlugin
 * Plugin URI: 
 * Description: Actualiza el stock de la tienda fisica
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: 
 * Author URI: 
 * License: GPL2
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'rudr_complete' );

function rudr_complete( $order_id ) {
    
    global $wpdb;    
//    $database="database";
//    $user="user";
//    $password="password";
//    $mydb = new wpdb($user,$password,$database,'localhost');

    //$db = new mysqli("localhost", $user, $password, $database);
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        
        
    mail("luilli.guillan@gmail.com", "fuera del bucle","viva el vino");
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

        $product        = $item->get_product();    
        $item_quantity  = $item->get_quantity(); // Get the item quantity               
        $item_sku = $product->get_sku();
            
        $cantidad = $item_quantity;
        $referencia = $item_sku;

        $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT `unidades` FROM `productos` WHERE `codigo_de_barras` = "'.$referencia.'"');
            
        mail("luilli.guillan@gmail.com", "dentro del bucle",$result);           
    }    
}?>
```

Comment: bien, ya esta solucionado. Ademas de agregar el `global $wpdb;` habia que recorrer el `$result` con un `foreach`.